# How to change the font size the display list (dropdown search)

Tags: flutter, dropdown

I'm trying dropdown search library but unable to change the font size in the display list (dropdown_search)?

```
 return new Container(
        child: DropdownSearch<Type2>(
          //  pop

          searchFieldProps: TextFieldProps(
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
            controller: _PropertyTypeController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
               
              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
              floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                onPressed: () {
                  _PropertyTypeController.clear();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          maxHeight: 300,
          dropdownSearchBaseStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
          onFind: (filter) => getTypeSuggestions(
            filter.toString(),
            
          ),

          dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
            labelText: "choose a Property Type",
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 0, 0),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
          onChanged: print,
          showSearchBox: true,

          popupShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
              topRight: Radius.circular(24),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0));
  }
```

The display font is big, would like to reduce to standard font size throughout the app.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure it's relevant to your question or not, but maybe it helps you

```
DropdownButton(
  value: selectedValue,
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,fontSize: 30),
  onChanged: (String? newValue){
    setState(() {
      selectedValue = newValue!;
    });
  },
  items: dropdownItems
  )
```

you can change font size and for more information visit this link:[Styling the dropdown](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-dropdown-list-flutter/#styling-dropdown)

if you are using dropdown_search 2.0.1 package from pub.dev then it's not possible because in textstyle there is no option to change font size of items. Here is all you can do with inputdecoration:

```
    (new) InputDecoration InputDecoration({
  Widget? icon,
  Widget? label,
  String? labelText,
  TextStyle? labelStyle,
  TextStyle? floatingLabelStyle,
  String? helperText,
  TextStyle? helperStyle,
  int? helperMaxLines,
  String? hintText,
  TextStyle? hintStyle,
  TextDirection? hintTextDirection,
  int? hintMaxLines,
  String? errorText,
  TextStyle? errorStyle,
  int? errorMaxLines,
  FloatingLabelBehavior? floatingLabelBehavior,
  bool isCollapsed = false,
  bool? isDense,
  EdgeInsetsGeometry? contentPadding,
  Widget? prefixIcon,
  BoxConstraints? prefixIconConstraints,
  Widget? prefix,
  String? prefixText,
  TextStyle? prefixStyle,
  Widget? suffixIcon,
  Widget? suffix,
  String? suffixText,
  TextStyle? suffixStyle,
  BoxConstraints? suffixIconConstraints,
  Widget? counter,
  String? counterText,
  TextStyle? counterStyle,
  bool? filled,
  Color? fillColor,
  Color? focusColor,
  Color? hoverColor,
  InputBorder? errorBorder,
  InputBorder? focusedBorder,
  InputBorder? focusedErrorBorder,
  InputBorder? disabledBorder,
  InputBorder? enabledBorder,
  InputBorder? border,
  bool enabled = true,
  String? semanticCounterText,
  bool? alignLabelWithHint,
  BoxConstraints? constraints,
})
```

Comment: @LKC are you using dropdown_search: ^2.0.1 package from pub.dev?

Comment: yeap..i m using dropdown_search: ^2.0.1

Comment: you can check this post for more help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65951144/i-want-to-change-the-textstyle-of-the-items-appear-in-dropdownsearch-which-comes
and please upvote my answers if it helps you